# How to get Column Names with EF6/MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I am using EntityFramework v6.1 with MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 v 6.8.3.0.

I am attempting to get the "Headers" or "Column Names" for data inside tables. I have a table called "dbases" and I need to get the Column Names from within ADO.NET, please help!

```
using (var connection = new hyperion_collectionsmaxEntities())
            {
                var portfolios = connection.portfolios.ToList();
                portfolios.ForEach(o => comboBox1.Items.Add(o.portfolio1));

                var statuses = connection.adminstatus.ToList();
                statuses.ForEach(o => chkLstBoxStatuses.Items.Add(o.statusname));

                //var headers = connection.dbases ?? <~~~
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to get at the column names is to query to MetaTables:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE information_schema.COLUMNS.table_schema = 'dbases';
```

There are a lot of interesting data there. For simply getting at the Column Name and the (default) Header you can use the DataTable.Column's properties:

```
yourTable.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnName 
yourTable.Columns[columnIndex].Caption
```

If EF has special ways I don't know about them.. but in the end imo the data should go into the DataTable..

Comment: That would require an SQL Query, I would like to know how to do this within the Entity Framework / ADO.NET. Could you assist me with that?

Comment: See my edited answer. But since I don't use EF (yet), I have to guess, if this will actually help you with your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately .Columns or anything of the sort is not supported with EF. >.< Thanks tho.